# Constructing Templated type for CGAL c++

Tags: c++, templates, cgal

So i have the following which should create a Delaunay triangle type for CGAL:

```
std::vector<Point> points = createPoints() // Fills points, This works. 
Delaunay dt(points.begin(), points.end());
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938311/cgal-help-getting-triangles-coordinates-from-delaunay-triangulation) question and the manual [here](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Triangulation_2_ref/Class_Delaunay_triangulation_2.html#Cross_link_anchor_1338). This should work, however I get the following error:

```
[100%] Building CXX object src/utilities/TriangulationVolumeCalculation/CMakeFiles/calculateVolumeDifference.dir/CalculateVolumeDifference.cpp.o
/home/uqbdart/SMG/sao2/src/utilities/TriangulationVolumeCalculation/CalculateVolumeDifference.cpp: In function â€˜void fillDelaunay(Delaunay&, std::vector<std::vector<double> >)â€™:
/home/uqbdart/SMG/sao2/src/utilities/TriangulationVolumeCalculation/CalculateVolumeDifference.cpp:31:37: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
/home/uqbdart/SMG/sao2/src/utilities/TriangulationVolumeCalculation/CalculateVolumeDifference.cpp: In function â€˜int main(int, char**)â€™:
/home/uqbdart/SMG/sao2/src/utilities/TriangulationVolumeCalculation/CalculateVolumeDifference.cpp:50:27: error: no matching function for call to â€˜CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<CGAL::Projection_traits_xy_3<CGAL::Epick> >::Delaunay_triangulation_2(std::vector<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick> >::iterator&, std::vector<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick> >::iterator&)â€™
/home/uqbdart/SMG/sao2/src/utilities/TriangulationVolumeCalculation/CalculateVolumeDifference.cpp:50:27: note: candidates are:
In file included from /home/uqbdart/SMG/sao2/src/utilities/TriangulationVolumeCalculation/CalculateVolumeDifference.cpp:3:0:
/usr/local/include/CGAL/Delaunay_triangulation_2.h:89:3: note: CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<Gt, Tds>::Delaunay_triangulation_2(const CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<Gt, Tds>&) [with Gt = CGAL::Projection_traits_xy_3<CGAL::Epick>; Tds = CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_2<CGAL::Projection_traits_xy_3<CGAL::Epick>, CGAL::Triangulation_ds_vertex_base_2<void> >, CGAL::Triangulation_ds_face_base_2<void> >]
/usr/local/include/CGAL/Delaunay_triangulation_2.h:89:3: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
/usr/local/include/CGAL/Delaunay_triangulation_2.h:86:2: note: CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<Gt, Tds>::Delaunay_triangulation_2(const Gt&) [with Gt = CGAL::Projection_traits_xy_3<CGAL::Epick>; Tds = CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_2<CGAL::Projection_traits_xy_3<CGAL::Epick>, CGAL::Triangulation_ds_vertex_base_2<void> >, CGAL::Triangulation_ds_face_base_2<void> >]
/usr/local/include/CGAL/Delaunay_triangulation_2.h:86:2: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
make[2]: *** [src/utilities/TriangulationVolumeCalculation/CMakeFiles/calculateVolumeDifference.dir/CalculateVolumeDifference.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/utilities/TriangulationVolumeCalculation/CMakeFiles/calculateVolumeDifference.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The manual states that:

```
 Precondition:  The value_type of first and last is Point.
```

Where first and last are the beginning and end iterator.

EDIT: I solved it by doing this:

```
Delaunay dt;
dt.insert(points.begin(), points.end());
```

Although it is fixed, the type declarations for the required iterator are the same according to the manual. Why would it fail in the constructor and not in the `insert` function.

Comment: Can you copy-paste the chain of typedefs that are used to define the type `Delaunay`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By any chance, would you be using an old release of CGAL ?  This constructor from range was introduced later than the insert() function, if memory serves me well.  Well, just check the code.

Comment: It was indeed introduced in 4.2

Comment: I am using the latest version of GAL, plus, wouldn't the compiler complain that constructor of that type doesn't exist rather then it has the wrong inputs?

Comment: Please double check which version of CGAL you are using.  It has to be 4.2 for the code to work.

Comment: Yep, you were right, i have CGAL version 4.1, I wonder how that happened.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is probably that your class `Point` do not have the required methods to be a template parameter of `Delaunay_triangulation_2` (that I guess you used to defined the class `Delaunay`)

What are the definition of the classes `Delaunay` and `Point`?

Useful examples can be found here:
http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Triangulation_2/Chapter_main.html

Comment: No point is a part of the CGAL lib. It is a typedef like this: `typedef K::Point_3   Point;`

Comment: Alright, seen your edit. Then I have no idea why it works in insert and not in the constructor. Though, the documentation specifies the concept `PointInputIterator` for `insert()`, and `InputIterator` for the constructor. Maybe there's a subtle difference, but I can't help you on this.